# About Real time database firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from my real time database in firebase however, the snapshot only prints the key but it doesn't the value. it prints null instead

this is my code in the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6f1O.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: When yuo're adding the code as text, please also add the data from the `Distance` node in your database (as text, no screenshots here either please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).